Angular deep linking with JWT bearer token in authorization header
How can I get the incoming request headers in an Angular authentication guard?
In an Angular 17 application, I'd like to support authenticated deep links with JWT tokens in the incoming request header, i.e., the request which starts the Angular application. The deep link is to a protected route, so an authentication guard is triggered but I cannot find a way to get to the HTTP request which started the application.
For example, in a "widgets" Angular application, a protected route might look like:
https://example.org/widgets/1234

Because it's a protected route, the widgets Angular application redirects to the login page. But instead of redirecting to login, the widgets application should use the incoming request's JWT authorization token to service the request:
GET /widgets/1234 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Authorization: <JWT TOKEN>

When this URL is selected, the Angular application starts and eventually the /widgets/1234 protected route is handed to the authentication guard. But the authentication guard has access only to route information; I cannot find a way to get the authorization header to avoid the redirect to the login.
Any ideas?
NOTE: I could add the JWT token as a URL parameter because the authentication guard does have access to that but I'd rather use headers than URL parameters to keep the token out of view.
NOTE: this is about incoming requests to an Angular application, not outgoing requests from an Angular application.

Guard does not fire when you start the application, it only intercepts requests made by HttpClient of angular! please refine your question with more details on what you want to solve! the more details the better

I think you're conflating interceptors and guards, Naren. The guard is triggered on a deep link because the "deep link" is a route in the Angular application...

that only applies for API calls, not for page or module loads!

I don't understand, Naren. I've added a bit more description to hopefully clarify what I'm trying to achieve.

From your question, there is a section in the docs Intercepting response events which helps us intercept the incoming response. You can use this code and docs, to perform logic only when the response is intercepted.
export function loggingInterceptor(req: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandlerFn): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
  return next(req).pipe(tap(event => {
    if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
      console.log(req.url, 'returned a response with status', event.status);
    }
  }));
}


Interceptors are used in Angular's HttpClient but my example is not about outgoing requests initiated by HttpClient (and their response), rather the question is about incoming request to a protected route in an Angular application.

@JanNielsen If you are not making the API call, you do not have access to these details. Here its the browser that makes the get request for the resource. You have to manually get the HTML through the httpclient, then access the headers, else find some way to pass the data, prefereably an API call

That's the rub, Naren :) and the reason for posting the question. This question is basically about getting more information about the initiating request which starts the widgets Angular application because it is that request which has the JWT token. As I noted, I could pass the token in the URL but I'd prefer to avoid that.

@JanNielsen Instead go for cookies, since this might help you read the data (I think cookies get automatically loaded and can be read), if not then just create an API to check the token!
